# Replace text inside WYSIWYG html

Tags: html, .net-core, html-agility-pack, wysiwyg, replaceall

I need to find and replace text inside html which comes from WYSIWYG editor in dotnet core app. I have no idea how to approach that.

For example replace ahoj, with joha in:

```
<b>aha</b> <b><i>b<b>a<i>a<div>h</div>o</i></b><i>ja</i> a<i><b>hoj</b></b> <b>foobar</b>
```

which would result in

```
<b>aha</b> <b><i>bajohaa joha</i></b><i> </i><b><i>foobar</i></b>
```

I was hoping that html agility pack could do such a think but I don't see how. Can you please point me to a right direction?

Kind regards
Teamol

Comment: What is the WYSIWYG editor? Different editors have different API to use in order to manage the content. Try first to investigate what is the editor you have, and then try more specifically to find answer for that specific editor, but at the end be prepared to write some JavaScript for that :)

Comment: I have only html so it does not matter from which WYSIWYG editor it is :)

Comment: As far as I know there's no way with plain HTML to have a WYSIWYG editor, thus you have to look closely to what you have. In addition, make sure that what you call a WYSIWYG is a real WYSIWYG editor like Froala Editor, TinyMCE, Setka Editor, Shorthand, Bubble, Vev, Synap Editor. Give some time to the editors I just shared with you to confirm that what you have on your side is close to what those editors provide.

Comment: WYSIWYG generates html and in dotnet core application I need to do find and replace. Sorry but I don't see how is this relevant to my problem.

Comment: OK, You are right. I confused with the way you wrote your question. Initially I though you have issue with the editor it self. Anyway, I am not .net developer but maybe this could help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0